# Retrieve data from different nodes firebase android studio

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, google-maps-markers

I can't retrieve the location from firebase to my app. Well, I did, but just one at time.

[structure here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fgxM.png)

I want retrieve lat and lng of all users, from firebase to put the markers in these coordinates on google maps. How can I do it?

Here's my MapsActivity:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private DatabaseReference mDataBase;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
   /* LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));*/



    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase
                            .getInstance()
                            .getReference()
                            .child("Estado")
                            .child("Cidade")
                            .child("Medianeira")
                            .child("Casa");

    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                double location_left = dataSnapshot.child("lat").getValue(Double.class);
                double location_right = dataSnapshot.child("lng").getValue(Double.class);
                LatLng sydney = new LatLng(location_left, location_right);
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
                //mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 24));
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "No data change", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            throw databaseError.toException();
        }


    });


}
```

Comment: Show your code. What have you done till now?

Comment: I can retrieve one pair of coordinates, not multiple on differents nodes :/